# database connection seems not to be working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to execute my `MVC` application, but I got a `NULL` exception when I want to display the
categories.   I follow the `MVC` music store example but I didn't used their db data.  I have 
a table called product and a table called category.  I added 2 products and 2 categories.
I will like to display the categories via the `INDEX`.  I am missing something but I can't find it.
Any way we can verify if the database is properly connected which seems not to be the case here.

Here is my Index from my StoreController

```
namespace WebStore.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        WebStoreEntites TP1StoreDB = new WebStoreEntites();

        //
        // GET: /Store/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           var categories = TP1StoreDB.Categories.ToList();  <== this show a null result

           return View(categories);
        }
```

Here is the webconfig which map my DB

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="WebStoreEntities" connectionString="Data 
    Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TP1StoreDB.mdf;Integrated 
    Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

It used to be like this before

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data  
   Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebStore-20140225063823;Integrated 
   Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebStore-20140225063823.mdf" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Here is the WebStoreEntities class

```
using System.Data.Entity;

    namespace WebStore.Models
    {
    public class WebStoreEntites
    {
        public DbSet<Produit> Produits { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Categorie> Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the error:   An exception of type `'System.ArgumentNullException'` occurred in `System.Core.dll` but was not handled in user code

Here is the categorie class

```
 namespace WebStore.Models
 {
    public partial class Categorie
    {
        public int CategorieId { get; set; }
        public string NomCategorie { get; set; }
        public List<Produit> Produits { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

And the produit.cs

```
 namespace WebStore.Models
 {
    public class Produit
    {
        public int ProduitId { get; set; }
        public int CategorieId { get; set; }
        public string NomProduit { get; set; }
        public Categorie Categorie { get; set; }
        public float Prix { get; set; }
        public int Quantite { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Exception please. Sarcastically saying - you are connected, just the database is wrong, so the question is totally wrong. THere is nothing wrong with the database connection. CHeck the data.

Comment: @TomTom  I added the exception

Comment: Not enough. That is starting to get FANCY. THat said, You really play around with sqlexpress and atachdbfilename? I hope that is meant as example, not as something for production. But no, that error is - not fun. DTry a manual db connection and goold old adi.net code just to establish a connection and make a select to check that part works.

Comment: Doesn't `WebStoreEntites` have to inherit from something? `DataContext`? I'm not an EF expert, someone else would have to chime in.

Comment: @TomTom I put the old connection statement, when you are saying a manual connection, you want I double click on the db under App_Data? Can you provide more details I am a beginner

Comment: I fixed this in the WebStoreEntities I was missing the DbContext  public class WebStoreEntites : DbContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the DbContext in my WebStoreEntities class

```
 public class WebStoreEntites : DbContext   <=== missing the DbContext
```